# Selenium Firefox/Web-Driver can't find element by XPath

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I'm having trouble reading a link inside a div.
Ok, here's what the div looks like:

```
<div id="AjaxStream" style="clear: both">
<a target="_blank" href="http://www.something.com/">
<img height="370" width="752" border="4" usemap="#Link" src="somefile.png">
</a>
</div>
```

The following code, to find the div works perfectly fine. 
(I tried element.getAttribute("id") - which returned "AjaxStream")

```
WebElement element = river.findElement(By.xpath("//html/body/div/div[2]/div/div[11]"));
```

And here is what's not working:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//html/body/div/div[2]/div/div[11]/a"));
```

This should actually fine the link-element, but it doesn't. Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

**##Edit:**
Nevermind - I fixed it. The problem was that the element wasn't loaded. I added a Thread.sleep(1000) before trying to find the element - and now it works perfectly fine.

Comment: to avoid using Thread.sleep you can use WebDriverWait.until

Answer (score 1):

try

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='AjaxStream']/a"));
String link = element.getAttribute("href");
```

//I need 6 characters but it's a 1 "char" fix

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at your xpath...to me that is unreadable. If someone comes in later in a few months, are they able to translate that xpath in to  tag you're looking for? A better solution would be a to add an id attribute to the  tag you are interested, and find it by that ID.

Comment: Well, another way to get the div element is this:
//div[@id='AjaxStream']
But I don't want the div - I want the link inside it. :/
And another way I tried to find the 'a' element: driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[@target='_blank']"));
This returns some links.. but the one I want is missing.

Comment: well you can chain right...so in your example it would be //div[@id='AjaxStream']/a[@target='_blank']